# Getting error after installed the chef in the node

Tags: chef-infra, devops, chef-recipe, chef-solo

While installing the chef on the node am getting the below error.

```
================================================================================
Error expanding the run_list:
================================================================================
192.168.1.11
Unexpected API Request Failure:
-------------------------------
Cannot load role preprodcron_role
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.11
System Info:
------------
chef_version=14.4.56
platform=ubuntu
platform_version=16.04
ruby=ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/usr/bin/chef-client
executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.11
Running handlers:
[2018-08-31T07:20:03+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2018-08-31T07:20:03+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
[2018-08-31T07:20:03+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2018-08-31T07:20:03+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2018-08-31T07:20:03+00:00] FATAL: Net::HTTPServerException: 404 "Object Not Found"
```

Please help chef is installed on the but there is no communication between the chef server and node.

Comment: Is the role present in chef server? How do you run chef-client?

Comment: Yes, I have created the role on the chef workstation under chef-repo/roles and using knife cmd I have installed the chef node on the node. knife bootstrap 192.168.1.25 --ssh-user ubuntu  --sudo --identity-file /home/ubuntu/staging.pem --node-name 192.168.1.25 --r
un-list 'role[preprodcron_role]' --node-ssl-verify-mode none

Comment: On your command list I do not see `knife role upload...`. Could you run `knife role list` to verify if it is really there?

Comment: knife role list
dev_role
dev_rolecron
preprod_role
prod_role
staging_role
These are the roles available in the chef workstation.